# Android: Bluetooth app file transfer issues

Tags: android, bluetooth, arrays, inputstream, outputstream

I am currently trying to make a file transfer app adapted from the Bluetooth Chat example.

My issue is that when I send the file across via bluetooth with an outputstream and receive it with an inputstream, the data sent and received from one device to the other are not the same.

The app is using a byte array for the transactions, while the receiving side has the byte array buffer set to 1024. So the device will be receiving in chunks, append the byte arrays as they come.

I have even tried sending a string of numbers across and changing the buffer size to 4 with no luck.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Can you please post your sending and receiving code?

Comment: I've realized what I was doing wrong, I was calling write one after another so the outputstream was not only sending the first batch of byte arrays but another batch parallel with the first call. So the data was all weird. Thanks for those who have spent time on trying to solve my problem

Comment: DroidDummy, would you mind posting the solution so that people who later come upon this question will be able to see how you solved it? You can accept the answer that you post and you'll get reputation points :)

Comment: I have yet to find a solution, basically, I need one thread to pause its execution until the other has finished using the outputstream.

Comment: Ah ok, well when you do get things working, please share the answer :)